# HTML: Ad-hoc Distribution - Cannot connect to local server

Tags: html, ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm testing out an ad-hoc distribution html file, hosting it on our local server. I don't really know much about this, just looking up what I can online, and I'm not knowledgeable enough to deal with the aforementioned issue.

Here's my project structure:

192.168.1.135/adhocDistributor:

- index.html
- project.ipa
- manifest.plist

Here's the code for `index.html`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample iOS OTA install</title>

</head>

<body>
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://192.168.1.135/adhocDistributor/manifest.plist"><font size="+4">Install the App</font></a>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the `manifest.plist` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>items</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>assets</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>kind</key>
<string>software-package</string>
<key>url</key>
<string><strong>https://192.168.1.135/adhocDistributor/project.ipa</strong></string>
</dict>
</array><key>metadata</key>
<dict>
<key>bundle-identifier</key>
<string><strong>com.yourcompany.TheElements</strong></string>
<key>kind</key>
<string>software</string>
<key>title</key>
<string>iOS Test App</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

I can view the html page from my iPad by going to `192.168.1.135/adhocDistributor`. Originally, the prior issue was

> Cannot install applications because the certificate for 192.168.1.135 is not 
>   valid

which I read could be solved by using https instead of http, but now I got this:

> Cannot connect to 192.168.1.135

I tried uploading those to an AWS S3 Bucket, but it gives me the same error, except now it's telling me `Cannot connect to s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: The index.html is only a helper to find the address `https://192.168.1.135/adhocDistributor/manifest.plist`
According to me :
1 - You must be able to reach this address with a web browser.
2 - The certificate has to be valid and verified (Most of the time the browser displays a green lock).

If those 2 conditions are not fulfilled, the install won't work

Comment: @Rafouille, yes, I can reach that address with a web browser. As for a green lock, well the one I uploaded to an AWS S3 bucket displays that, so is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: If you attempt to use adhoc distribution, the device has to be declared in **certificates and profile** portal. Then the **provisioning profile** should as well include the device. Please post meaningful error otherwise others won't be able to help you.